# How to use createTransport with new version of Network.Transport.TCP?

Tags: haskell, cloud-haskell

I used the network-transport-tcp-0.5.1 for creatipn TCP transport.

```
resultCT <- createTransport host port defaultTCPParameters
```

But now I'm using the package  network-transport-tcp-0.6.0 and getting an error because of the new type:

```
createTransportExposeInternals
  :: N.HostName
  -> N.ServiceName
  -> (N.ServiceName -> (N.HostName, N.ServiceName))
  -> TCPParameters
  -> IO (Either IOException (Transport, TransportInternals))
```

How can I use default value for (N.ServiceName -> (N.HostName, N.ServiceName))?
Maybe there are some examples?
Thank you!

Comment: I do now createTransport (host app) (port app) (\_ -> (host app, port app)) defaultTCPParameters. Is it correct?

Comment: You should [edit] additional information into your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you choose a `port`, `createTransport` might not use the given port. For example, you might use the port `"0"`, which means that *any* port might get used. Depending on the used port, the external host name or service can differ vastly. For example, your firewall will only forward the ports 1000-2000 on `a.qspider`, and 2000-3000 on `b.qspider`. Therefore, if you bind on 1320, your external host and service name would be `a.qspider:1320`.

Alternatively, you have configured your ports to forward `8080` to `80` externally, so the `ServiceName` `8080` would result in `80` + external address.

All in all the additional parameter provides you a method to handle external port forwardings and host names correctly. If you don't have any external networks at that point, you can simply use

```
createTransport host port (\port' -> (host, port')) ...
```